# GoogleMap showing all cars marker with correct bearing

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am building a Taxi app, and I manage to add all the cars with marker icon of a Taxi to their exact location.

But for some reason, all the icons are looking towards wrong direction,

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

But I am getting:

[image]

My Code:

Here I am just setting the bearing I get for every car from the server as the rotation of the marker, but I am not sure how should I calculate the rotation taking in consideration the actual icon which as an Image it faces left already.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    vehicleImage = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.taxi);
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
    mMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);

    for (Vehicle vh : vehicleList) {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().rotation(vh.bearing).position(new LatLng(vh.latitude, vh.longitude)).icon(vehicleImage).flat(true));
    }


    mMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(this);
}
```

Comment: Please add in your code so that we are able to reply to your question accurately

Comment: Yes, add code, which shows how you are trying to rotate the car.

Comment: @YikJin Just added some code and extra info.

Comment: @Tapani Just added some code and extra info.

Comment: Is the bearing from the LocationManager?

Comment: @Tapani Yes the one that I get from the Vehicles are from LocationServices with GoogleApiClient. Once I get the location updates i can call getBearing On Location.

Comment: What is the returned bearing when the car points to west as in your screenshot?

Comment: @Tapani well at the moment its 0 and its facing west

Comment: @MoAdel And the car image is such that the front is upwards?

Comment: @Tapani no the car image itself is to the left

Comment: @MoAdel What do you expect to happen when in the car image the front points to west and you rotate it 0 degrees? Of course it still points to west, not north as you expect. The bearing is the difference from the north so you need to add 45 to the bearing if the car image points to west by default.

Comment: @Tapani.. lol.. my bad I didn't know that the image has to be facing north.. my bad.. thanks for pointing it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The front of the car should point up in the original image because bearing is measured from north. Or, if the front of the car points to left (west), you have to add 45 degrees to the bearing.